# Prince skips coronation - planet gets irradiated. Nemesis uses ex-military pirates

Tags: story-identification

Maybe 15 years or so old?

A five book SF series. Written jointly by two authors.

One of the main characters is a prince who skips out on his coronation/naming day ceremony which is a good thing as the planet gets invaded and the palace gets irradiated by an old adversary who was shown mercy and imprisoned instead of executed.

I think the father's name was Galen? Or maybe that was the prince's name?

Anyway, the old enemy employed pirates to do his dirty work as he wasn't allowed to have a military anymore. One of them uses a proscribed technology (called a LOGOS, I think?) to increase his tactical prowess...

There might have been the word "Phoenix" in the title of the series, or one of the books?

I know they went out of print fairly quickly, and are hard to find...

Answer (score 8):

The [Exordium series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?3429) by Sherwood Smith and Dave Trowbridge. The main character is Brandon nyr-Arkad.

1. *The Phoenix in Flight* (1993)
2. *Ruler of Naught* (1993)
3. *A Prison Unsought* (1994)
4. *The Rifter's Covenant* (1995)
5. *The Thrones of Kronos* (1996)

Books 2 and 4 were the hardest to find, iirc. The authors have been updating them and releasing them (slowly!) as [ebooks on Book View Cafe](http://www.davetrowbridge.com/exordium/).

Comment: That's it! Thank you VERY much!